# How to watch history of console in chrome dev-tools?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Recently I was writting an important code, but did it in chrome dev-tools (sounds weird, I know). When I went away my pc restarted, but I didn't worry because after writting I pressed enter to save it in cache of chrome. So after restarting my pc I opened my chrome and tryed to find my js code that as thought I save in cache, but I didn't find anything. The fun thing is some codes in chrome have saved and I can use them unlike than my code.

Probably is there the way with that I can look all history of inserted codes in console of dev-tools?